# Get file objects inside a scope of "with" block

Tags: python, with-statement

For example there's with statement:

```
with open("ACCELEROMETER", 'w') as ACCELEROMETER,\
    open('GPS', 'w') as GPS,\
    open('LIGHT', 'w') as LIGHT,\
    open('LOCATION', 'w') as LOCATION,\
    open('MIC', 'w') as MIC,\
    open('SCREEN', 'w') as SCREEN,\
    open('TIME', 'w') as TIME:
```

I want to get file objects just created using some python code : 
I'm looking for equivalent of [dir function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) for local scope of **with**.
Is it possible?

Comment: huh?  What do you want to do here ... do you want a list `[ACCELEROMETER, GPS, LIGHT, ...]`?  And why do you want that?  Perhaps a different approach would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't really possible (without making some assumptions) since `with` doesn't create a new namespace.  You could create a file-list object which is implemented as a context manager ...

```
class FileList(list):
    def __init__(self, files, mode='r'):
        list.__init__(open(arg, mode) for arg in files)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        for fobj in self:
            fobj.close()

with FileList(["ACCELEROMETER", "GPS", ...], mode='w') as fl:
    for fobj in fl:
        ...
```